# Retornar mensagem de erro ao dividir por 0 - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tudo bem?
Estou fazendo um desafio em Ruby e as def's precisam ser do jeitinho que está no código que vou mandar.
A divisão por 0 precisa retornar com a mensagem "Opa! Zero como divisor"
Estou tentando já faz um tempinho mas ainda não consegui chegar nesse resultado, sempre me apresenta o erro

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/calculadora_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require 'calculadora'

SyntaxError:
  /home/leticia/Documentos/campos_code/calculator/lib/calculadora.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting end-of-input
# ./spec/calculadora_spec.rb:2:in `require'
# ./spec/calculadora_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00004 seconds (files took 0.26173 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

Meu código está assim:

```
def soma(primeiro_numero, segundo_numero)
    primeiro_numero+segundo_numero
end

def subtracao(primeiro_numero, segundo_numero)
    primeiro_numero-segundo_numero
end

def multiplicacao(primeiro_numero,segundo_numero)
    primeiro_numero*segundo_numero
end

def divisao(primeiro_numero,segundo_numero)
    primeiro_numero / segundo_numero
    end
ZeroDivisionError
    puts "Opa! Zero como divisor"
end
```

Conseguem me dar um help?
Fiz algumas alterações também e meu último código ficou desa forma

```
    def divisao(primeiro_numero,segundo_numero)
if segundo_numero != 0
    return primeiro_numero/segundo_numero
elsif primeiro_numero = 0
    puts 'Opa! Zero como divisor'
else segundo_numero = 0
    puts 'Opa! Zero como divisor'
end
```

Mas realmente ainda não funciona. Já olhei as apostilas do curso, vídeos no YouTube, perguntei pro coleguinha e nada, realmente travei

Answer (score 2):

Interessante usar a ideia de "Guard Clause"

```
def divisao(primeiro_numero, segundo_numero)
  return 'Opa! Zero como divisor' if segundo_numero == 0 
  primeiro_numero / segundo_numero
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Após muita conversa e código, conseguimos chegar no resultado. Precisa de um end a mais ao final da última função.
Pelo que conseguimos entender, um end "fecha" o if e o outro end "fecha" a função
O código ficou assim:

```
def soma(primeiro_numero, segundo_numero)
    primeiro_numero+segundo_numero
end

def subtracao(primeiro_numero, segundo_numero)
    primeiro_numero-segundo_numero
end

def multiplicacao(primeiro_numero,segundo_numero)
    primeiro_numero*segundo_numero
end

def divisao(primeiro_numero,segundo_numero)
    if segundo_numero != 0
        return primeiro_numero/segundo_numero
    else 
        return 'Opa! Zero como divisor'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def divisao(primeiro_numero,segundo_numero)
    begin
        puts primeiro_numero / segundo_numero
    rescue ZeroDivisionError
        puts "Opa! Zero como divisor"
    end
end

divisao(10,2) # =>  5
divisao(10,0) # => Opa! Zero como divisor
```

Comment: Tenta explicar melhor sua resposta...

Comment: @EduMendonça Por que você não tenta ajudar a pessoa com o problema, ao invés de negativar minha resposta? Eis a hipocrisia!

Comment: Não és, eu já fui negativado varias vezes por dar respostas sem explicação, não quero que ouras pessoas passem pelo mesmo problema e outra não é o proposito do stackoverflow.com deixar uma resposta sem um explicação logica. seu código pode responder a pergunta mais as pessoas que receberem a resposta vão ficar sem o por que desse código servir para ela. É o mesmo que responder "porque sim."  para um criança...

Comment: "não quero que ouras pessoas passem pelo mesmo problema". Ai você vai lá e faz a mesma coisa que fizeram injustamente com você, comigo. Era só dar um toque nos comentários, cara, fica a dica!

Comment: Velho não sou eu, é o sistema do pt.stackoverflow.com eu só analiso como qualquer outro que pode fazer, e outra eu não negativei eu só sinalize como baixa qualidade se alguém negativou nem eu e nem você vai saber quem foi...

Comment: @EduMendonça nessa serei obrigada a concordar com o Maicon Santos. Fazer com o colega o que não gosta que façam com você não faz muito sentido.

Comment: Gente Eu só falei para ele explicar melhor a resposta e não só deixar um código lá como resposta eu a resposta dele apareceu na fila de análise e eu comentei eu não votei negativo  só comentei como todas as outras pessoas fazem comigo... quando eu deixo um código solto... sem explicação com resposta...

Comment: Quando vocês tiverem pontos suficientes para faze analise das perguntas e respostas  vão entender....